# PHP read CSV different after CSV modified

Tags: php, csv

I have a php read csv function, it reads all fine and it reads row by row and turn them into array. It all works fine.

```
private function readCSV($csvFile){
        $file_handle = fopen($csvFile, 'r');
        while (!feof($file_handle) ) {
            $line_of_text[] = fgetcsv($file_handle, 1024);
        }
        fclose($file_handle);

        return $line_of_text;
    }
```

However after the CSV file been modified, eg. just change one of the value and save it again, and read the csv with the script. it read the CSV differently.

result below:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => id
            [1] => title
            [2] => phone
            [3] => fax
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 2
            [1] => asd
            [2] => 61430055509
            [3] => 
        )

    [2] => 
)
```

after save the csv and read again

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => id
            [1] => title
            [2] => phone
            [3] => fax
            [4] => 2
            [5] => asd
            [6] => 61430055509
            [7] => 
        )

    [1] => 
)


while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
                $data = $result;
                $row = array_merge($row, $data);
                if(!$flag) {
                  // display field/column names as first row
                  fputcsv($out, array_keys($row), ',', '"');
                  $flag = true;
                }
                array_walk($row, array($this, 'cleanData'));
                fputcsv($out, array_values($row), ',', '"');
            }
```

Comment: its not the reading at issue, its the saving, your not ending the lines properly

Comment: o really? but when i open the doc it appear two lines of data tho Thx Dagon

Comment: post the first 2 lines, before and after

Comment: actually even no change just save it, it somehow wont read the line break... maybe its the MS Excel on mac cause the issue?

Comment: macs use \r windows \r\n and *nix \n so it could well be a line break issue

Comment: o ok i c, Thanks Dagon for you kind help!

Comment: btw so how can i detect if start the next line, so the array appear correctly

Comment: show your code writing the file, i assume your using fputcsv()

Comment: Yes i have edit the write code as well thanks again Dagon