# use csv list to update a MySQL field

Tags: mysql

I have csv list which contains bounced emails addresses, one per line.

```
example1@example1.com
example2@example2.com
example3@example2.com
...
example700@example12.com
```

I need to change the **user_state** for each of these email to **'email_bounce'**.

With the following SQL query i can do the changes using one email address at a time.

```
UPDATE xf_user SET user_state = 'email_bounce' WHERE email = 'example1@example1.com';
UPDATE xf_user SET user_state = 'email_bounce' WHERE email = 'example2@example2.com';
```

and so on

I made a copy of the DB where i would like to do a dry run but i have no idea how to automate this SQL query to go through all the emails in my csv.

Comment: Please read [mcve].

Comment: Here is an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17893875/php-read-csv-different-after-csv-modified